# Text alignment bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, vote-to-close

I just discovered a graphics bug when looking at the Close Vote pop-up. You can see below that there are text alignment issues for the close reasons that already have a vote count next to them. I noticed this on two different questions. I'm running Chrome 61.0 on Windows 10.

[image: vote-to-close bug]

Comment: Also for me, running IE11 on Windows 7.  It wasn't like this yesterday; I'm not sure when I started noticing it today.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Alignment issue in the Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289054/165773) (FWIW similar issues can be found in some other dialogs, these are side effects of particular recent change)

Comment: @gnat And now I don't see the issue anymore. Looks like maybe the fix finally made its way down the line?

Comment: given that developer is working on fixing this bug (and couple similar ones) right now it is entirely possible that fixed code has been just deployed, yes. Note that it's still possible for some users still see buggy old code due to [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching)